# Is there any difference between these two sentences?

Tags: differences, definite-articles

Is there any difference between these sentences apart from structure?

> The tiger is a ferocious animal.
> Tigers are ferocious animals.

Comment: Largely addressed at [the function of **the** in the following sentence](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/198880/the-function-of-the-in-the-following-sentence/199009#199009) (though as JasonR says below, the definite generic is more formal).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you say "The tiger", it is a stand-in for "all tigers"; apart from having to make the subject and verb agree, the two sentences are the same.

You can use the same equivalence in other cases that don't look exactly the same:

"Man is mortal." / "All men are mortal."  (Note that in this usage, "men" is gender-neutral.)

"Humankind is fallible." / "All humans are fallible."

"Art nurtures the soul." / "The arts nurture the soul."

Comment: Good examples, except that *the arts* has a broader meaning than *art*: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_arts

Comment: @z7sg - Just because Wikipedia sez it, don't make it so.  I do agree that "art" generally refers to "the visual arts", but "Art" refers to all arts - the fact that it's the first word of the sentence did obscure the capitalization, it's true.  The epigram "_Ars longa, vita brevis_" (Art is long, but life is short) is ascribed to Hippocrates, and I never heard of him picking up a brush.

Comment: I didn't mention painting.  Here two clearly distinct meanings 1, 2 http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/art#m_en_gb0041510.004

Comment: @z7sg - Also, amusingly, where the Wiki entry says "It is a broader term than 'art'"... if you click the word "art", the first paragraph begins: <<Art is the product or process of deliberately arranging items (often with symbolic significance) in a way that influences and affects one or more of the senses, emotions, and intellect. It encompasses a diverse range of human activities, creations, and modes of expression, including music, literature, film, photography, sculpture, and paintings. >>  So pffft to the logical consistency of Wikipedia.

Comment: Put more simply, "art" can refer to the "products of creativity" whereas "the arts" can't.  So it isn't equivalent in the same way as "the tiger"/"all tigers".  Maybe I am being pedantic, but that's half my motivation here.

Comment: @z7sg - 1) as I mentioned above, I had in mind "[Art with a capital A](http://www.google.com/search?hl=&q=art+with+a+capital+a)", which I think is a much better parallel with "the arts" than just plain "art".  2) If you want to be quite that pedantic, then "The tiger" can mean "[a groom in livery](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tiger)"(sense 3) or "[the shriek or howl at the end of a cheer](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/tiger)"(way, way down the page) - which, clearly, "all tigers" cannot.

Comment: @z7sg: Clearly @MT_Head doesn't need my help defending his position, but I would just point out that in the context of his specific example it would be somewhat perverse (not just pedantic) to infer the more restrictive sense of *Art* in such a lofty statement. Sure, you can imagine a context where the 'lesser' meaning really *was* intended, but in that case it would likely be obvious regardless of the trivial capitalisation ambiguity.

Comment: @FumbleFingers There is no 'lesser meaning' and it has nothing to do with capitalisation.  There is no **authoritative reference** I can see saying there is a difference between *Art* and *art*.  Whereas 'the arts' is a very common expression with a particular meaning as you can see in the Oxford dictionary where it has its own entry.  I can see an EL&U question is needed here to put both of you straight.

Comment: @z7sg: As you wish. I'll change my mind if and when it becomes apparent significant numbers of people translate *"Ars longa, vita brevis"* as *"The arts endure, but life is fleeting"*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers No idea what you are trying to say.  The Latin is just to show off though right?  My point has been completely vindicated by the answers to my question.  Actually turned out an interesting read, despite being inspired by MT_Head's intransigence.

Comment: @z7sg: It's not really worth arguing about. No-one's denying that 'The arts' or 'Art' can be distinguished from 'art' if they're actually being juxtaposed in order to highlight a distinction. But I'm glad you've been interested and/or educated by the answers you got there, and I can only regret you haven't been able to do that in *this* comment thread.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Not educated, vindicated.  If it wasn't worth arguing about you wouldn't be stubbornly persisting with your mistake.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference.
 Both refer to the fact that the tiger is an animal, and a ferocious one.

Answer (score 1):

No real difference.

I would say the second one ("tigers are ferocious animals") would be more common in everyday speech or writing.

The first one ("the tiger is a ferocious animal") sounds like it would be in a more formal setting like a documentary film or TV show about tigers, or in a research paper, when you are talking about "the tiger" as a collective animal species.