# What is the difference, if any, between 'art', 'the arts', and 'Art'?

Tags: meaning, differences

In answer to [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/28715/is-there-any-difference-between-these-two-sentences/28719#comment-50171), there was some discussion about whether these two sentences are equivalent:

> Art nurtures the soul.
>   The arts nurture the soul.

Are they equivalent?

'The arts' is a common but woolly term and 'art' is notoriously difficult to pin down.  Oxforddictionaries.com gives the following definitions:

> 1. **art** [mass noun] the expression or application of human creative skill and imagination, typically in a visual form such as painting or sculpture, producing works to be appreciated primarily for their beauty or emotional power
> 2. (**the arts**) the various branches of creative activity, such as painting, music, literature, and dance

What practical differences in usage are there (if any)?

Also, does *Art* (capital A) have a special meaning distinct from *art* (lower case a)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at etymology

**[art](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=art)**

> early 13c., "skill as a result of learning or practice," from O.Fr. art (10c.), from L. artem (nom. ars) "work of art; practical skill; a business, craft," from PIE *ar-ti- (cf. Skt. rtih "manner, mode;" Gk. arti "just," artios "complete, suitable," artizein "to prepare;" L. artus "joint;" Armenian arnam "make;" Ger. art "manner, mode"), from base *ar- "fit together, join" (see arm (1)). In M.E. usually with sense of "skill in scholarship and learning" (c.1300), especially in the seven sciences, or liberal arts. This sense remains in Bachelor of Arts, etc. Meaning "human workmanship" (as opposed to nature) is from late 14c. Sense of "cunning and trickery" first attested c.1600. Meaning "skill in creative arts" is first recorded 1610s; especially of painting, sculpture, etc., from 1660s. Broader sense of the word remains in artless.
>
> Fine arts, "those which appeal to the mind and the imagination" first recorded 1767. Expression art for art's sake (1836) translates Fr. l'art pour l'art. First record of art critic is from 1865. Arts and crafts "decorative design and handcraft" first attested in the Arts and Crafts Exhibition Society, founded in London, 1888.

Shows how the meanings evolved from a wider meaning into a more narrow one. In context of Bachelor of Arts, it is obvious that it refers to "**skill** in scholarship and learning".

Today when we talk about artist and art the immediate association are paintings, sculptures and other "works to be appreciated primarily for their beauty or emotional power".

However some connotations from older meanings still remain:

- in the expression "art of making something" we don't refer to l'art pur l'art, but we refer to **craftsmanship** (an older meaning)
- in slightly metaphorical sense, "art of..." can be taken to mean **skill**, as in art of persuasion, art of motorcycle maintenance ([wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zen_and_the_Art_of_Motorcycle_Maintenance)), art of war, rather then art that is normally exhibited in a gallery
- in "college of arts and sciences", arts refer to "studies intended to provide general knowledge and intellectual skills"
- in [artless](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/artless), the 1st meaning lists: "lacking art, knowledge, or skill", extending the semantic to include knowledge and skills in what should be a direct antonym

Also, from wikipedia on [the arts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_arts#The_various_arts)

> In the Middle Ages, Artes Liberales (liberal arts) taught in medieval universities as part of the Trivium: (grammar, rhetoric, and logic) and the Quadrivium (arithmetic, geometry, music, and astronomy), and the Artes Mechanicae (mechanical arts) such as metalworking, farming, cooking, business and the making of clothes or cloth. The modern distinctions between "artistic" and non-artistic skills did not develop until the Renaissance.

I think it is reasonable to assume that such usage as in the above influenced etymologies of many other terms and I think it is easy to justify, even today, usage that when talking about arts encompasses *skill* and *craftsmanship*.

As for capitalized *the Art* - you will find it referring to almost anything; for more colorful examples see magic, alchemy and so on. Actually any kind of human activity can be called "art of..", and especially in the writings it is often the most appropriate word to describe studies of such interests. In those cases practitioners usually refer to their subject simply, and sometimes deliberately cryptic, as *the Art*.

Answer (score 4):

"Art" is an abstract. Its primary use is as an abstract quality. It can also be used as a collective noun for objects (or activities) characterised by art (the quality).

"The arts" is a different kind of abstract: it is not a quality, but an aggregation of activities (not usually objects) that are characterised by art.

So "art nurtures the soul" *could* mean that the aggregation of works of art (or artistic activities) nurtures the soul, but is far more likely to mean that the abstract quality "art" nurtures the soul.

"The arts nurture the soul" would to me mean the somewhat different idea that the aggregate of artistic pursuits (and perhaps their results) are what nurtures, rather than the abstract quality they share.

Answer (score 2):

I would say "the arts" are a set of disciplines (each of which is "an art"), "art" without the article refers to the end result of those disciplines, typically (but not strictly) to the end result of the visual arts.

For example when you say "making music is an art" you tend to be talking about the talent of the performer / composer, while if you say "music is art" you typically think about the enjoyment of the listener.  On the other hand, if you say "I enjoy art", people will typically think you like looking at paintings or sculptures, not many people would expect you to be referring to music or gastronomy.

Another quirky note - while you can say "cooking is an art", it's much harder to say "good food is art" - perhaps because the end result isn't permanent, or not something we would typically think of as "artistic"?

Answer (score -1):

***The arts*** refers to literature, fine arts and performing arts. The term ***art*** usually means fine arts, but can also refer to technique and creativity.

Comment: Not my downvote.