# Nominalizing adjectives regarding nationalities

Tags: word-usage

When we talk about nationalities, "Americans" and "the Americans(or the American people)" are two ways of saying the same thing with the latter having a collective sense. 
The same is true for "Italians" vs. "the Italians(or the Italian people)", "French people" vs. "the French(or the French people)", "Japanese people" vs. "the Japanese(or the Japanese people), etc.
Is it perfectly fine to say "the American (as a plural)" to mean the same as "the Americans or the American people"; "the Italian (as a plural)" instead of "the Italians or the Italian people" to refer to them as the nation as a whole?

Comment: No; the singular refers to one person, not to the people.

Comment: Which means "the American people" can't be shortened to "the American" with no change in meaning?

Comment: Only in a context where it’s very clear that _people_ is understood, and even then not ideally. You _might_ get away with saying, “The American people numbers over 300 million; the Italian only about 60 million”, but even there it would be more natural to just repeat the noun.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet When describing, for example, national characteristics is it now too dated to say something like "The Belgian, like the Englishman prefers drinking beer". One can use a singular noun to refer to the collective with such as "the elephant is larger than the bison", so why not "the native American is descended from Asians who came across the Behring Straits".

Comment: @WS2 I don’t think those are too dated, but they’re synecdochical – they’re using the singular as a typical representative of its group. So you might say that the Belgian, like the Englishman, likes **his/her** beer, but not that the Belgian likes **their** beer. To me at least, this usage doesn’t mean the same thing as the people: the singular specifically means ‘the average, stereotypical X’, whereas the plural means ‘the collection of Xes as a whole’.

Comment: @WS2 My understanding is that the generic use of "the", which you seem to be talking about, is restricted. Have I mislearned it?

Comment: Essentially answered at ['the function of _the_ in the following sentence'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/198880/the-function-of-the-in-the-following-sentence/199009#199009) (see John Lawler's link to a paper where he addresses the _definite generic noun phrase_ ).

Comment: Essentially answered at ['the function of _the_ in the following sentence'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/198880/the-function-of-the-in-the-following-sentence/199009#199009) (see John Lawler's link to a paper where he addresses the _definite generic noun phrase_ ). _The American_ / _Americans_ / _The American people_ are semantically interchangeable in this sense.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth Are you implying "the American" can have a collective sense to refer to the people of America?

Comment: That's what Professor Lawler says, isn't it? Here you can find two examples from an example from [New Essays on The American
edited by Martha Banta, Professor of English Martha Banta](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=DW-4H2ntoA8C&pg=PA63&lpg=PA63&dq=%22The+American+would%22&source=bl&ots=PkiS3GVeCy&sig=ACfU3U0_1O3qR8ne_Dgz08iq3KDGL45ciA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj4wdiJ94TjAhWRX8AKHS9VAQcQ6AEwCXoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22The%20American%20would%22&f=false).

Comment: Ah, I think I've understood your question at last. I've rolled back from my edit. // You can say 'Americans / the Americans /  American people / ??the American people / an American like/likes baseball', but only, normally, 'the Americans  took back Luzon'. I think you need to bring out the distinction between 'the typical American' and _America seen as a nation_. I find 'When we talk about nationalities, "Americans" and "the Americans(or the American people)" are two ways of saying the same thing with the latter having a collective sense. ' very misleading....

Comment: And I think you're confusing the issue. It would be very unusual to say 'An American took back Luzon'. Or 'An Englishman won the Napoleonic War'.

Comment: https://www.englishforums.com/English/TheNationality/jlvcp/post.htm  Please refer to the posting by Cool Breeze, which seems to make sense to me

Answer (score 3):

Some national adjectives are taken as *plural* nouns when used alone: e.g. "the British", "the English", "the Welsh", "the Scottish", "the Irish", "the French", "the Japanese", "the Chinese", are easily used to refer to the people as a whole. (This may possibly have to do with the words' endings.)

Some national adjectives are *singular* nouns when used alone: "the American", "the Canadian", "the Mexican", "the Egyptian", "the Italian", "the Australian", all mean individuals, unless used in a metaphorical or generic sense ('the typical American....', 'the [Ugly American](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ugly_American_(pejorative))').

"The Turk" is an individual; "the Turkish" are his people.

Comment: Yes, there appear to be lexical gaps. The man from Azerbaijan / Belize / Brunei / Burkina Faso / Chad.... Though I believe I've come across 'Japanese' and 'Chinese' as representing singular individuals (I wouldn't call these count usages; I've never heard 'two Japaneses', for instance).

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth: Adjectives like "the Azerbaijani" and "the Iraqi" are also singular, but there are traps for the unwary: a citizen of Afghanistan is "an Afghan" (make no puns about other American uses of that word), while if you say "an Afghan**i**" you are referring to the national currency, parallel to the US Dollar or UK Pound. // And no, per my comment above about some adjectives being plural _when used alone_, one can say "two [or any higher number] Japanese" (French, Welsh, etc.) without adding "s". To indicate a singular, put a noun afterward: man/woman/person/citizen.