# "37% of Japanese" vs "37% of the Japanese"

Tags: definite-articles, numbers

When we refer to certain nationalities, we tend to add "the" to indicate that we are talking about the people and not the language if there is an ambiguity.

Example:

> The Chinese speak Mandarin.

We could omit "the" and add "people" after the nationality to do the same thing.

Example:

> Chinese people speak Mandarin.

Omitting both "the" and "people" doesn't seem to be correct in general.

However, it seems that we tend to omit "the" when speaking about the statistics of certain nationalities.

Example:

> Only 37% of Japanese considered Americans “honest.” [[Bruce Stokes; Pew Research Center](https://www.pewresearch.org/short-reads/2015/04/09/how-americans-and-japanese-see-each-other/)]

What is the rationale or reasoning behind this omission? It seems to be something specific that happens when we use numbers.

Related : [Nominalizing adjectives regarding nationalities](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/502844/nominalizing-adjectives-regarding-nationalities)

Comment: I don't think there is any 'rule' here. They might just as easily have said "37% of the Japanese".

Comment: It's not '% of Irish' etc specific. In the article you link to, Stokes includes << As part of our recent survey of the relationship of Japanese and Americans, we asked the publics in both countries if they associated particular words with people in the other country. >>

Comment: To me, this is obviously a case where parallelism didn't work. Apparently the author was looking for a comparable plural relating to Japanese people as a group of individuals (similar to Americans, Bolivians, Egyptians, Russians, Germans) and fell into a trap. One wouldn't have said "% of British" or "% of French" or "% of Polish," but would have said "% of Britons" or "% of Spaniards" etc.

Comment: @Robusto This is an example of changing usage being acceptable to some but not to others. Checking examples from the Google ngrams FF displays shows that there are a lot of cases where the definite article is dropped from its traditional place before the nominalised adjective. As do raw Google searches. But I'd say this is only for demonyms, and as FF says (I didn't!) 'not all demonyms are treated equally in this respect'.

Comment: The Pew piece drops the article along the way, and not to start with. By then we know it's the surveyed people of each group.

Comment: It could be viewed as dropping the noun "people" in situations where it's understood. "37% of Japanese people" would be unarguably correct. In giving statistics it's common to only give the relevant facts, the things which have changed, and it would be tiresome to type out "people" dozens of time. (Just as psephologists say "don't knows" rather than "people who answer don't know".)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: I knew when I added ***as commented by Edwin...*** that I wasn't being completely accurate there. But presumably the fact that you chose ***Irish*** was in fact significant. You couldn't really mention ***British*** in the same way because of ***Britons*** - but I had to pop out  immediately after posting my answer, so I never got around to commenting / asking you if there might be a gender-neutral blanket term for ***Irishman, Irishwoman***. Anyway, there it is asked now. Plus - are you content with my revision to *...as **alluded to** [by your comment]*?

Comment: In recent years saying "the x" to refer to a group of people has been been getting looked at less favourably as well. AP tweeted about it earlier this year and I know of at list one local council who recommend it not being used anymore and instead suggest going for "x people". Take from that what you will.

Comment: Yes, it very much does seem to be something that happens when we use stats/numbers.

Answer (score 3):

A couple of centuries ago we [almost always included the article](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=of%20the%20Japanese%20are%2Cof%20Japanese%20are&year_start=1819&year_end=1869&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) when using ***Japanese*** (or ***Chinese, Portuguese***, etc.<sup>1</sup>) as a plural noun meaning *Japanese / Chinese / Portuguese **people***...

[image]

...but things have changed significantly since then, and [the usage chart for recent decades is very different](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=majority%20of%20the%20Japanese%20are%2Cmajority%20of%20Japanese%20are&year_start=1940&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=10)...

[image]

So at the moment it's effectively a stylistic choice - unless you're obliged to follow some specific style that insists on one form or the other.

Given the *speed, extent,* and *direction* of change, I suggest learners drop the article in their own text, but be prepared to accept it from others. There is no real concept of "right" or "wrong" here, just an ongoing usage shift.

---

<sup>1</sup> But note that - as alluded to by @EdwinAshworth - not all [demonyms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demonym) are treated equally in this respect. Most people [still keep the article with ***the** Irish,*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=of%20the%20Irish%20are%2Cof%20Irish%20are&year_start=1819&year_end=1869&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) for example.

Comment: I'd estimate that about 50% of the hits for "of Japanese are" are false positives such as 'forms of Japanese are', 'phonotactics of Japanese are'. However' a substantial number of hits are true examples with 'Japanese' = 'Japanese people' (= 'the Japanese')..

Comment: 'Of Irish are' is obviously better to enter in a search than 'Irish are', but the relatively large number of hits of the type/s 'number of Irish are' / 'majority of Irish are' / 'lower orders of Irish are' do seem to bolster OP's suspicion that a number/%ge / quantifier / pseudo-partitive seems regarded as affording more licence to drop the article. //// One nice false positive is 'The first and the last of these are only employed for the coarser fabrics, and the common sorts of Irish are also used for the same purpose'. I suspect it's not whiskey.

Comment: If it's purely stylistic, would "Only 37% of the Japanese considered Americans honest" would also be acceptable. But I feel very compelled to put a noun after "Japanese". Does this sound at all natural to you?

Comment: @E.N That is not acceptable to me. I think there's two phenomena here: The selection of *the* or not, but I think "Only 37% of Japanese" is more like elision of "people" than non-selection of *the*.

Comment: @E.N: I doubt many if any native Anglophones would care about the lack of a "noun only" term (such as ***people***) after demonyms like ***Japanese, Irish,...*** The issue is simply whether they care about the definite article (the) ***before*** it. As of now, some do, some don't. It's not really important whether 50% of the article-less hits contributing to my chart are "false positives" - the shift is so extreme that the point I'm making remains valid even if Edwin's observations are completely true.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Does prepending ***majority*** to my ***of** [the] **Japanese are*** search terms give you any more confidence in the validity of the second chart?

Comment: Looking at individual examples certainly encourages support for your 'have changed' but I'm not sure about your 'significantly'. But I'm pretty sure the change _is_ occurring.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Anyone who *doesn't* believe usage has changed *and continues to change* in this area must be away with the fairies. To my mind, the only issue is that *some* native speakers don't like / resist / underplay the change. On average I'll probably continue to include the article myself (when we reach a certain age, we naturally become more linguistically conservative! :) - but if I was a younger non-native Anglophone learning the language today, I'd definitely want to get behind the curve on this one!

Comment: The old are with us always,